# Migrating to @ConfigurationProperties with naming conflicts

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, configuration, javabeans

I have a Spring Boot application with an `application.properties` file that looks like this:

```
setting.mode = a # Can be either `a` or `b`
setting.mode.a.subsetting1 = abc
setting.mode.a.subsetting2 = def
setting.mode.b.subsetting1 = ghi
setting.mode.b.subsetting2 = jkl
```

We used to use `@Value` annotations to read these values, so it didn't matter that the name of the String `setting.mode` is the same as the prefix of the "sub-settings".

I was given the task of cleaning up this application, and I want to move to using `@ConfigurationProperties` with a large configuration object that matches the content of the properties file in order to make the code easier to work with.

I was thinking that the structure of the configuration class would look something like this (Kotlin example, but it doesn't matter):

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("setting")
class MyProperties {

    // Has the value either `a` or `b` to tell us which component to use
    lateinit var mode: String

    // THE PROBLEM IS HERE
    // -------------------
    //
    // The two classes below need to be under the `mode`
    // prefix, but they can't be because it is already used
    // to get its String value above.

    val a = A()

    val b = B()

    class A {
        lateinit var subsetting1: String
        lateinit var subsetting2: String
    }

    class B {
        lateinit var subsetting1: String
        lateinit var subsetting2: String
    }
}
```

---

Note that the value of `setting.mode` is also used to decide which bean to register:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = ["setting.mode"], havingValue = "a")
fun a(properties: MyProperties): CommonInterface {
    return A(properties.mode.a)
}

@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = ["setting.mode"], havingValue = "b")
fun b(properties: MyProperties): CommonInterface {
    return B(properties.mode.b)
}
```

---

How can I set up this configuration (without having to rewrite the `application.properties` to remove the naming issue for all instances of this application)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to do this is *not* to have a single `ConfigurationProperties` class with all the nested classes to build the whole structure, because that means you are unnecessarily filling in parts that you know will not be used because their corresponding beans are not registered.

The best way to do this is to split out configuration classes `A` and `B` like this:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("setting.mode.a")
class AProperties {
    lateinit var subsetting1: String
    lateinit var subsetting2: String
}

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("setting.mode.b")
class BProperties {
    lateinit var subsetting1: String
    lateinit var subsetting2: String
}
```

Then change the `@Bean` definitions to use these classes directly instead of calling for the entire configuration object:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = ["setting.mode"], havingValue = "a")
fun a(properties: AProperties): CommonInterface {
    return A(properties)
}

@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = ["setting.mode"], havingValue = "b")
fun b(properties: BProperties): CommonInterface {
    return B(properties)
}
```